# How to compress JS data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have a Rails + React app that is ~3mb (too big!)

About 2mb of that is a single instance variable, `@songs`, that's passed to the react component like this:

```
<%= react_component('SongApp', songData: @songs, songId: @song_id, allBooks: Book.reactify) %>
```

By passing the data in like that, I can immediately use it as `this.props.songData` in the component.

I want to compress this data (which is a JSON string)—so the client device doesn't need to download so much—and decompress within the React component on the client device. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Rack::Deflater**

**Rack::Deflater** middleware compresses responses at runtime using deflate or trusty ol’ gzip. Inserted correctly into your Rack app, it can drastically reduce the size of your HTML / JSON controller responses

Add it to config/application.rb thusly

```
module YourApp
 class Application < Rails::Application
   config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater
 end
end
```

**Answer Number 2**

For the response to be in gzip format we don't have to change the render method call.
If the request has the header Accept-Encoding: gzip, Rails will automatically compress the JSON response using gzip.

If you don't want the user to send a request with preset header., you can add the header to the request manually in the controller before rendering the response:

```
request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'] = 'gzip'
render :json => response.to_json()enter code here
```

check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dblock/1451946)